# Django: CreateView not saving to database

Tags: django, create-view

I'm a Django newbie and have been really struggling with the piece of code that allows a user to register for my site.  I have the model, the form displaying correctly on the html page and am not getting any errors, but the data posted by the form is not getting created in the database.  I've researched and tried numerous code but the issue persists.  I'm praying someone can take pity and help!  Thank you in advance!

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name','email', 'password']
```

views.py

```
class RegisterPage(CreateView):
    template_name = 'register.html'
    form_class = UserForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

def form_valid(self, form):
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
    return super(RegisterPage, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Try overriding the `form_invalid` method and printing out form.errors and form.non_field_errors to see if there's a hidden error somewhere

Comment: You can see the validation errors in your view after form submission if any. Did you see any? or have you got any errors?

Comment: have you check for indentation cause the form_valid method should be inside the RegisterPage class.

Comment: You guys are awesome, I figured out how to highlight form errors on submission and a random hidden field (username, which appears to be required) emerged.  Once I added username to the form and tried again it saved to the database.  Thank you all!